# Save an image from the project

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, qgis-processing

I took a tif file and cropped it to a portion using Raster>Extraxtion>Clip Raster by Extent. My project name is OBIA. After cropping the image is saved to this project. How do I download this image?[image]

Comment: Do you mean saving or downloading?

Answer (score 1):

When you select Raster>Extraxtion>Clip Raster by Extent there is an option to save file

Answer (score 0):

You either mention the path and name of desired file when clipping, by pushing the ... near result empty line, or if the layer is already in the project, you click right on it and choose Save as..